# How can I do the following validation using knockout js? 

Tags: knockout.js

How can I do the following validation using knockout js? I have the following view model:

```
function ViewModel () {
        var self = this;
        self.ListName = ko.observable();
        self.Current = ko.observable();
        self.MyVideos = ko.observableArray();
    }
```

Where MyVideos have the following structure:

```
    [{
                "VideoID": 1,
                "VideoName": "First Video"
    },
    {
                "VideoID": 2,
                "VideoName": "First Video"
    }]
```

So Current and VideoId are the relation, and I want to render the VideoName with the self.Current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `Current` is the `VideoId` and you want to display the `VideoName`.  For that scenario you could do:

```
self.CurrentName = ko.computed(function() {
    var currentId = self.Current();

    var currentVideo = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.MyVideos(), function(video) {
        return currentId === video.VideoId; 
    });

    return currentVideo ? currentVideo.VideoName : 'none';

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loosely using this quickly written code. It create a computed to find the first array item and its VideoName property. Of course, add error checking, too.

```
self.Current = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.MyVideos()[0].VideoName;
});
```